# In quantum search algorithm, how to interpret the effect of $U(t)$ as a rotation on the Bloch sphere?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, hamiltonian, quantum-computer

In Nielsen's QCQI, in page 259, it reads,

$$U \left ( \Delta t \right ) = \left ( \cos^2 \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) - \sin ^2 \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) \vec \psi \cdot \hat z \right ) I $$ $$-2 i \sin \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) \left ( \cos \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) \frac {\vec \psi + \hat z} 2 + \sin \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) \frac {\vec \psi \times \hat z} 2 \right ) \cdot \vec \sigma$$ where $U \left ( \Delta t \right )$ is a operation of a Hamiltonian, $\Delta t$ is the time interval, $\vec \psi$ is the initial state.

Well, it seems complicated. But with $\vec r = \cos \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) \frac {\vec \psi + \hat z} 2 + \sin \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) \frac {\vec \psi \times \hat z} 2 $ and $ \vec \psi \cdot \hat z = \frac 2 N -1$ 
 where $N$ is the number of the elements in the search space, it would be simplified to $U \left ( \Delta t \right ) = \left (1-\frac 2 N \sin^2  \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) \right ) I -2 i \sin \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) \vec r \cdot \vec \sigma$.

Then the book reads, $U \left ( \Delta t \right ) $ is a rotation on the Bloch sphere about an axis of rotation $\vec r$ and through an angle $\theta$ defined by $\cos   \left ( \frac {\theta} 2 \right ) = 1-\frac 2 N \sin^2  \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right ) $.

My problem is, the definition of the rotation by $\theta$ about any $\hat n$ axis is $ R_{\hat n} \left ( \theta \right ) = \cos \left ( \frac \theta 2 \right ) I - i \sin \left ( \frac \theta 2 \right ) \hat n \cdot \vec \theta$. Then in this case, $\sin \left ( \frac \theta 2 \right ) = 2 \sin \left ( \frac {\Delta t} 2 \right )  $.

Then $\sin^2 \left ( \frac \theta 2 \right ) + \cos^2 \left ( \frac \theta 2 \right ) \neq 1$.

Where have I made a mistake?